# Having trouble creating a stopwatch timer with Calendar class

Tags: android, timer, stopwatch

I have been having a little trouble using the Calendar class to create a stopwatch timer.  For some reason, my program keeps crashing when this piece of code is called.  I tried using other classes such as Timer & Date, but the same thing happened.  My code is as follows:

```
private OnClickListener clearButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        fullTime = calendar.HOUR + ":" + calendar.MINUTE + ":" + calendar.SECOND
                    + ":" + calendar.MILLISECOND;

        timeTextView.setText(fullTime);
    }
};
```

Should I use another class (other than the Stopwatch class) to fix this problem?  Thanks a bunch.

*Please do not vote down on this post.  If this post is unclear in any way, please express your concern in the comments section. Thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialised the "calender" or "timeTextView"? Maybe you can post the exception first.
initialise calender by call Calendar.getInstance();

Comment: Yeah I have tried that, but I still got an error.  When you say post the exception, do you mean I should put the calendar.set commands inside a try ... catch flow?

Comment: When I run the program in the simulator, it just says "Unfortunately, Stopwatch has stopped."